# Is Tobi the same as Obito, disguising as Madara?

Tags: naruto

Beginning around episode 140 of *Naruto Shippuden*, after Itachi's death, Tobi is seen going around a lot, either with Sasuke, or showing his "real?" face to Kisame as the one who is controlling the Mizukage.

It seems that the general consensus from what I've heard is that Tobi is Obito, but Kisame says it is Madara when he seems him, and of course Tobi tells Sasuke that he is Madara, and it seems like Itachi believed Madara was alive so it would seem to add up that he was Madara.

Is the Tobi that was doing all of this Obito, disguising himself as Madara, and for what reason did he need to?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/50015/why-was-kisame-surprised-when-he-saw-obito-tobi-fake-madara-without-the-mask-t

Answer (score 1):

Now first of all, if you want to know whether Tobi is Obito, then there's a youtuber out there called '2spooky' and he has posted a video that clears that part.

Now to why Obito was referring to himself as Madara.

Madara's had the dream of creating the ideal world. But he won't be able to do that at his old age. So, in order to get resurrected with rinne rebirth jutsu, Madara implanted his rinnegan to newborn Nagato. But even so he still needed a successor to him who can persuade Nagato into to using rinne rebirth jutsu. And that successor was Obito.

But Obito didn't have a name for himself in the shinobi world. He is just a kid thought to be dead in the war. If he tried to live with his true name, he could do particularly nothing. But since Madara was a name known far and wide in the shinobi world, he went with that alias. With this alias he could persuade Nagato in turning akatsuki into a rouge ninja association, and he could strike fear into people.

Hope this helped.